# Javascript Croppie. Crop image from url on the client and then save

Tags: javascript, html, crop

Im using the library [Croppie](http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/#documentation) . It works correctly when it receives an url that points to a image saved on the server. However it doesn't work if it receives a url from some image on the web:

Works:

```
$('.demo').croppie({
    url: 'demo/demo-1.jpg',
});
```

Doesn't work:

```
$('.demo').croppie({
    url: 'http://magic.wizards.com/sites/mtg/files/image_legacy_migration/mtg/images/daily/wallpapers/Wallpaper_JuganTheRisingStar_1280x960.jpg
});
```

I just want to know if there is a possible workaround. Or do I have to save the image to the server and then crop it?

Ok so I created a JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/alejoss/borcp2kq/

The question is clear on the JSFiddle. It doesn't work at the moment.

Comment: can you put together a plunker or jsFiddle or a code snippet showcasing the problem?

Comment: also, check your console to make sure the image was actually loaded rather than blocked. Might be a CORS problem.

Comment: @SoluableNonagon Ok so I created a JSFiddle. Please let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: The issue is `Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy`. So you have to load and save the image.

Comment: @SoluableNonagon sry for that. Didn't save external resources on the JSFiddle. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Croppie is using `canvas.drawImage(...)` to manipulate images so it doesn't work when it is from a different domain because of CORS policy.
The workaround I found is to encode the image from the external source to base64 in the server and pass it to Croppie.

In Server(PHP):

```
$base64Image = base64_encode(file_get_contents('http://external_resource_link'))
```

In Javascript:

```
var myExternalImage = "data:image/png;base64,<?php echo($base64Image); ?>";

var imageCropper = $('#upload-container').croppie({
     viewport: {
        width: 250,
        height: 150,
        type: 'square'
     },
     boundary: {
        width: 300,
        height: 200
     },
     url: myExternalImage
});
```